# Check IF one String contains the same characters as another string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring, nscountedset

I am trying to write a function which will allow me to determine whether one `NSString*` contains the characters of another `NSString*`. As an example, refer to the below scenario:

```
NSString *s1 = @"going";
NSString *s2 = @"ievngcogdl";
```

So essentially when the comparison between these 2 strings occurs, it should return true as the first string `s1` has the same characters of the second string `s2`. Could I use an `NSCountedSet`? I know that this class has a method `containsObject:(id)` although I don't think that will solve my problem. Is there any other ways in completing this function and provide me the required results?

Comment: For just a few cases I'd maybe take each character from the first string, put it in an NSString, and do `rangeOfString` on the second.  If I had to do a bunch of searches against the second string I'd put the characters (converted to NSNumbers) in a set and search the set with one character at a time from the first string.  But Droppy's way is probably a good compromise all around (though one could speed it up a hair by extracting both strings as unichar arrays before beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this method could be rather slow, but I would still favour it over `[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]`, which requires creating an `NSCharacterSet` object per comparison:

```
- (BOOL)string:(NSString *)string containsAllCharactersInString:(NSString *)charString {
    NSUInteger stringLen = [string length];
    NSUInteger charStringLen = [charString length];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < charStringLen; i++) {
        unichar c = [charString characterAtIndex:i];
        BOOL found = NO;
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < stringLen && !found; j++)
            found = [string characterAtIndex:j] == c;
        if (!found)
            return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. If I were to implement it using [NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet: @], would it be faster? Even though I would be creating an instance of the object per comparison?

Comment: @Maff You'd have to time it to be sure, however creating an object is not cheap and `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` must be iterating over the string anyway, so we may as well keep it simple and do the iteration ourself.

Comment: Definitely agree. I will try both out though and see how I go. I will let you know the results; in terms of speed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This solution doesn't handle the situation where the first string contains a single instance of a letter but the second string contains two instances of that letter - as in your example "ievngcogdl" and "going".  It returns YES for "ievngcodl" and "going" although there is only a single g in the comparison string

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't see that as a requirement from reading the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure - I was merely assuming based on the double g

Comment: @Maff Will have to clarify.

Comment: Yes. I will need to consider repetitive characters.

Answer (score 2):

This will work -

```
-(BOOL) string:(NSString *)string1 containsInputString:(NSString *)string2 {

    // Build a set of characters in the string

    NSCountedSet *string1Set = [[NSCountedSet alloc]init];

    [string1 enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string1.length)
                                options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                 [string1Set addObject:substring];
                             }];


    // Now iterated over string 2, removing characters from the counted set as we go
    for (int i=0;i<string2.length;i++) {
        NSRange range = [string2 rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:i];
        NSString *substring = [string2 substringWithRange:range];
        if ([string1Set countForObject:substring]> 0) {
            [string1Set removeObject:substring];
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will definitely this solution also a shot! Quick question, based on the logic outlined above, it looks like the `string1` method parameter is the one which contain the longer character set? Is that correct? So from my example above it would be: `s2`?

Comment: Yes, I switched string1 and string2 to make the method name nicer :)

Comment: If you use this, make sure you use my updated code - The initial version didn't initialise the counted set properly

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  It works for your test case in your question.  What is the test case for which it fails

Comment: Sorry Paul I was believe that I was calling the inbuilt method name for strings named containsString, which was only returning me exact matches. All is good now.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably change the method name to avoid a clash

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot call this method in an IF statement? It does not recognize this method for some reason, even with the changed method name.

Comment: I am trying to call like this `[word1 containsInputString: anotherWord]` in an IF statement, although it does not work. Why is this?

Comment: To work that way you would need to put this method in an NSString category.  If it is just a method in your class then you would call it as `[self string:word1 containsInputString: anotherWord];`

Answer (score -1):

**Regular Expressions** are the best way to check this type of conditions and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147263/regular-expression-to-check-if-string-contains-specified-characters) once

Below I am adding the code for your solution, please check once

```
  NSString *s1 = @"going"
  NSString *s2 = @"ievngcogdl";

  if ([self string:s1 containsSameCharacterofString:s2]) {

            NSLog(@"YES");

  }


    - (BOOL)string:(NSString *)str containsSameCharacterofString:(NSString *)charString
    {

        if (charString.length >= str.length) {

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"^[%@]+$", charString] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

            NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, str.length);
            NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:str options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];

            return (matchRange.location != NSNotFound);

        }
        else {

            return NO;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is that different from `[NSString isEqualToString:]`, other than being more expensive and cumbersome to use?

Comment: For large strings, iterating over the whole string is going to be expensive, so it is better to use regular expression for this type of conditions.

Comment: Try with `NSString *s2 = @"i";` and tell me what the method returns.

Comment: modified answer check once.

Answer (score -3):

```
BOOL containsString = [@"Hello" containsString:@"llo"];
if (containsString) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: It comes with the latest build of the Foundation framework in Xcode 6. It works like an NSPredicate i.e. [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", string]; I thought the answer/method name is fairly self explanatory and it works, hence the +1.

Comment: This is not a method on `NSString` read the Apple Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html) Where in this documentation is this method? And because it doesn't exist this is the reason for the 4x downvotes. This answer is incorrect

Comment: This is in NSString.h in the foundation framework: `/* containsString: returns YES if the target string is contained within the receiver. Same as calling rangeOfString:options: with no options, thus doing a case-sensitive, non-literal search. localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString: is the case-insensitive variant. Note that it takes the current locale into effect as well.  Locale-independent case-insensitive operation, and other needs can be achieved by calling rangeOfString:options:range:locale: directly.
 */
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);`

Comment: If this satisfies you please could you take away the - points

Comment: Whether or not the method exists it doesn't meet the requirements of the question as they are not looking for a substring but rather for the letters in any order